# Calling Stored Procedure from MSAccess fails, but running the exact same command from Sql Server Manager works

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, stored-procedures

I have an Access DB that has a bunch of linked tables from a SQL Server database. The Access DB calls a stored procedure on the SQL Server database that updates data on a form.

```
Dim sql As String
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
cnn.ConnectionString = "DSN=Records"
cnn.CommandTimeout = 90
cnn.Open

sql = "exec myStoredProcedure @param1=" & Me.txtParam1Field & ", @param2=" & Me.txtParam2Field

cnn.Execute sql

Set cnn = Nothing

frmMyForm.Requery
```

When I run this it either times out, if the CommandTimeout value isn't long enough, or it executes, but doesn't actually execute `myStoredProcedure` for some reason. If I take the string sql and past it into Sql Server Manager, myStoredProcedure executes in less than a second and everything works great.

I've tried debugging over this code in Access, but I'm not getting any useful results when I step over `cnn.Execute sql`.

Comment: Maybe bad parameter sniffing? http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2007/11/27/parameter-sniffing/ Honestly there isn't a lot of information here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the values of txtParam1Field and txtParam2Field you probably want to enclose the values with single quote like so:

```
sql = "exec myStoredProcedure @param1='" & Me.txtParam1Field & "', @param2='" & Me.txtParam2Field & "'"
```

If we take your original code and assume that txtParam1Field is equal to 1 and txtParam2Field is equal to John then your generated sql will not execute because it will look like this:

```
exec myStoredProcedure @param1=1, @param2=John
```

Your best bet is to output the value of "sql" variable in debug window and run that exact statement in sql query manager. That will tell you exactly where the problem is if it's malformed SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting the Prepared property to false on the command object.  This causes a recompile of the procedure before execution, but could result in a better plan depending on the parameters that are sent.

```
Dim sql As String
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim Cmd As ADODB.Command

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
cnn.ConnectionString = "DSN=Records"
cnn.CommandTimeout = 90
cnn.Open

sql = "exec myStoredProcedure @param1=" & Me.txtParam1Field & ", @param2=" & Me.txtParam2Field

Set Cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set Cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn
Cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
Cmd.CommandText = sql
Cmd.Prepared = False
Cmd.CommandTimeout = 300
Cmd.Execute
```

Comment: Is that true when the command is executing a stored procedure? I didn't think it was force a recompile of the procedure but my memory could be failing me.

Comment: @Brian: You should review your answer. There is no variable named Cmd in the questions code.

Comment: Sorry, it's a property of the command object.  I edited my answer to reflect how it's used.  @Sean: I think it does because i know I've fixed performance issues with this before.